# Вызов события onClick в одном компоненте при срабатывании onClick в другом в React приложении

Tags: reactjs, javascript-events, onclicklistener

В моем React приложении отображаются данные по транспортным средствам. Есть список машин в виде меню и по нажатию на какой либо пункт меню отображается соответствующий контент.
Кроме того, есть также google карта, на которой отображаются текущие местоположения машин.
Так вот вопрос. Как реализовать возможность отображения контента по нажатию на маркер на карте? То есть, допустим, была выбрана в меню 1 машина и по ней отображаются данные. Я нажимаю на карте например на 3 машину и в меню выделяется 3 пункт и данные начинают отображаться по 3 машине...
Мне удалось связать нажатие на маркер и выделение соответствующего пункта меню по атрибуту состояния Menu.Item (active). Но по моему это не перспективно, потому что как теперь заставить отобразиться нужный контент мне непонятно..
Может есть какой то способ передать onClick в другой компонент? То есть, нажатие на какой то элемент в одном компоненте вызывает нажатие в другом (сымитировать событие, нажатие)?

В случае необходимости могу выложить код. Мне бы просто узнать принцип передачи события между компонентами, это вообще возможно?

Comment: это возможно, но лучше так не делать, так как в таком таком коде будет сложно разобраться
лучше придерживаться вертикальной связи компонентов сверху вниз. самый верхний компонент, может в качестве потомком иметь и карту и машины и всё что угодно. потомки имеют коллбеки и пропсы. колбек вызывает соовествующий обработчик на родителе, а тот отправляет пропсы в других потомки. ведь вам нужно, не чтобы эмулировался клик, а чтобы менялись данные в этом компоненте, значит данные должно приходить как пропсы

Comment: но если вы хотите горизонтальную связь, то есть refs. но всё это уже проверено практикой, вертикальная модель победила. если данных много и действий много, можно начать смотреть в сторону  менеджера состояния  (редакс и тд)